# On direct product of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

By definition,

A group $G$ is a **direct product of the subgroups** $N_1, N_2, ... , N_k$ if an only if

$i.$ $G=N_1N_2...N_k$

$ii.$ For each $j$, $N_j  \cap(N_1N_2...N_{j-1}N_{j+1}...N_k)=e$, and

$iii.$ Each of $N_1, N_2, ..., N_k $ is normal in $G$.

My question is... Is the second condition the same as saying

$(a)$ $H_i \cap H_j =e$ for $i \neq j$ ?

I am proving something. Now, I'm having difficulty in showing $(ii.)$. However, it will be easier if $(ii.)$ is the same as $(a)$. Thank you.

Comment: If $N_i$ intersects the product of other $N$'s trivially, then it intersects each of them trivially, since each of them is a subgroup of their product.

Comment: But the converse needs not be true if other assumptions are not met. Consider $G=S_3$. $\langle(12)\rangle$ intersects both $\langle(13)\rangle$ and $\langle(123)\rangle$ trivially, but not their product, the whole group $S_3$.

Answer (score 1):

No that is not the same. Look at the elementary abelian group of order $4$. The three subgroups of order $2$ have pairwise trivial intersection. However, already the product of two of them (doesn't matter which) is the full group. So condition (ii) is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same as given by Sebastian Schoennenbeck. You can even find a similar counterexample using vector spaces.

Let $V$ be a two-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ (viewed as an abelian group). Let $x,y$ be a basis for $V$. Then $\left\langle x\right\rangle, \left\langle y\right\rangle, \left\langle x+y\right\rangle$ are three subgroups having mutually trivial intersections. But $V\neq \left\langle x\right\rangle\oplus \left\langle y\right\rangle \oplus \left\langle x+y\right\rangle$.